# Create column with a list of col1 based on col2 col3 combinations Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Really hard question to phrase.

df looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3
123     1       0
456     0       1
789     1       0
234     0       1
```

trying to make a col4 that looks like this:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
123     1       0       [123,789]
456     0       1       [456,234]
789     1       0       [123,789]
234     0       1       [456,234]
```

***rows 1 and 3 are the same and rows 2 and 4 are the same***

The code i've got is:

```
data = [
    [123,1, 0]
    , [456,0, 1]
    , [789,1, 1]
    , [234,0, 1]
]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

# Code
n = 2
cols = ['col2','col3']
combos = list(itertools.combinations(cols, n))

for combo in combos:
    col1_list = df.groupby(combo).apply(lambda df: list(df['col1'].unique()))
    col1_list
```

The error i get is:

```
KeyError: ('col2', 'col3')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
# Code
n = 2
cols = ['col2','col3']
combos = list(itertools.combinations(cols, n))
for group in combos:
    print(df.groupby(list(group))['col1'].apply(list))
```

output :

```
col2  col3
0     1       [456, 234]
1     0       [123, 789]
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I do have a ton more columns though - really need to use the combo in the for loop, rather than type all the columns out

Comment: ok I think , you really want to group by different combination of columns , is that right ?

Comment: @max see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```py
col = data[['col1','col2']]
```

You have to turn the columns you want into a list, within the selection of columns.